# android spell checker - can it be improved?

Tags: java, android, string, spell-checking, prediction

I have been looking at the android spellchecker example in the sdk samples. the hellospellchecker is working but seems to be utterly useless.

Most strings return no suggestions and others are unhelpful.

e.g.
"tihs" returns 1 suggestion "this"
"helo" returns 3 suggestions "he'll" "help "believe"
"tabble" returns no suggestions

The SampleSpellChecker example appears to do absolutely nothing.

Is there a way to make the checker better? How else can one provide a spell checker (I basically want a list of likely words returned when a word is entered)?

I have seen that the spellchecker framework is ment to provide the same as is used when sending a text on an android phone however it is not working nearly as well.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html describes the framework but I don't find it very helpful and quite hard to understand

have been at this all day, any help greatly appreciated